# Storage Pool Keeps Disconnecting After Reboot on Hyper-V

Tags: windows, hyper-v, storage-spaces

I have a File Server installed on Hyper-V with Windows Server Datacenter 2012. I created a Storage Pool in the Hyper-V Session.

When I reboot the host, the server hyper-V session is in saved status. I noticed that the host picked up the storage pool with a yellow triangle. I have tried combinations of the following commands I found online. After I run the commands the triangle goes away, but I still cannot boot the Hyper-V.

In order to boot the hyper-V I would have to delete the storage pool from the host and placing the HDDs in offline mode. Now the HyperV boots, however if I boot just the HyperV then its good. When I reboot the Host the StoragePool disappeared.

```
Set-StoragePool -FriendlyName NAS | -IsReadOnly $False
Get-StoragePool -FriendlyName NAS | Get-VirtualDisk | Set-VirtualDisk -IsManualAttach $False -Access:ReadWrite
Get-StoragePool -FriendlyName NAS | Get-VirtualDisk | Connect-VirtualDisk
Get-Volume

Get-VirtualDisk
Set-VirtualDisk -FriendlyName NAS -IsManualAttach $False

Get-VirtualDisk | Where-Object {$_.IsManualAttach -eq $True}
Get-VirtualDisk | Where-Object {$_.IsManualAttach -eq $True} | Set-VirtualDisk -IsManualAttach $False
```

Comment: Your PS scripts are synactically wrong

Answer (score 1):

Storage Spaces is only supported on physical hardware.  If you're trying to pass the disks through to a VM, you're going to see the host recognize a foreign storage pool on every reboot, as you described.

You should run the storage pool on the host, not the guest.  Then put a fixed-size VHDX on the virtual disk from the storage pool.  Then attach that VHDX to the VM.  You'll see the same behavior that you're hoping for, but it will actually work.

Most people who are doing what you're doing say that their reason for trying it that way is that it will perform better.  It won't unless you're running many hundreds of thousands of IOPS through the system.   And if you're doing that, just create more than one VHDX.

Lastly, you should change the default on your VM so that it shuts down cleanly when the host shuts down, and the restarts when the host restarts.  As long as you're running a guest OS that's recent, this will work faster and more cleanly than saving the guest.